# Invalid query: Data too long for column 'x' at row 'y'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Haven't been able to find a useful solution for this yet, so I'm going to fire away. I keep running into this error whenever I try to run my verification script.

We run a database management system for various schools and we collect the data for that entire school when the first user from that school registers (the superadmin, as it were). When subsequent members of staff from that school register, their register-entries are then checked against the database to link the new registree against the correct member of staff (if applicable, of course).

To avoid errors whenever members of staff have the same surname/initials (which of course is quite likely), I am working on a verification script that automatically starts up whenever the amount of people with similar initial/surname combinations occur.

```php
$sql=("SELECT `idStaff`, `Staff` FROM `mldb`.`staff`
WHERE `Staff` LIKE '%$in%$sn'");

$qu=mysqli_query($dbc,$sql);
id=mysqli_fetch_array($qu);

if (mysqli_num_rows($qu) > 1)
   {
     load ('duplication.php') ;
   }
```

On the duplication page, a full loop of all the members of staff (with their full name and subject area) are printed where the user can click on their corresponding name. The hyperlink in these names redirect to the verification script, which looks like this:

```php
{
    echo '<p>We have found multiple entries with that name. Please verify who you are.</p>' ;
            {               
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
                    {
                        echo '<br><a href="verification.php?id='.$row['idStaff'].
                        '"> ' . $row['Staff'] . ',  ' . $_SESSION['School'] . ', '  
                        . $_SESSION['SubjectArea'] . ' </a>' ;
                    }

            }
```

Below is the verification script which (should) update the registered user table to add the staff ID and full staff name to the registered user so that they will never show up as duplicate anymore.

```php
if(isset($_GET['id'])) $id = $_GET['id'];
        {
            $s = "SELECT DISTINCT `Staff`
                  FROM `mldb`.`staff`
                  WHERE `idStaff` = $id" ;

            $e=$_SESSION['Email'];

            // This doesn't work - why? //
            $q="UPDATE `mldbadmin`.`user`
                SET `idStaff`='$id', `Staff`='$s'
                WHERE `Email` = '$e' AND `idStaff` IS NULL";
            $r=mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) ;

             if (!$r)
                {
                    die('Invalid query:' . mysqli_error($dbc));
                }

                    else
                        { header("location:confirmeduser.php") ; }
        }
```

However, I get the error message shown in the topic header when I run this script, which I can't work out why it happens - because all the columns should be able to handle all this data.

```
Invalid query:Data too long for column 'Staff' at row 1
```

I feel I am missing out something really obvious here but I've been stuck on this for quite a while now. Is there anybody who could help me out with what I am doing wrong? Many thanks!

Comment: $s is a string comprising "SELECT DISTINCT `Staff`
                  FROM `mldb`.`staff`
                  WHERE `idStaff` = $id" that you're trying to store in the Staff column.... how large is that column defined as? Are you really trying to store a query string in your database column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to save SQL query *text*, not executing it. Looking to your script and assuming sense of your `Staff` column you should do:

```
        $s = "SELECT DISTINCT `Staff`
              FROM `mldb`.`staff`
              WHERE `idStaff` = $id" ;

        $e=$_SESSION['Email'];

        // Look that your $s is inside ( .. )
        $q="UPDATE `mldbadmin`.`user`
            SET `idStaff`='$id', `Staff`=($s)
            WHERE `Email` = '$e' AND `idStaff` IS NULL";
```

-i.e. applying your SQL, stored in `$s` as *subquery* Another option may be execute query for `$s` separately.

Hint: you should care about substituting user data into SQL directly, since it's vulnerable to SQL injections.

Comment: I was not aware of such thing as a query within a query - That explains why trying to add a result command to my query gave me more problems then answers, because I then would have to add a fetch_row command. Thanks!